# FB chat plugin error on CORS policy and customerchat net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-chat

I got an error implementing the code below inside the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="fb-customer-chat" class="fb-customerchat">
</div>
<script>
  var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
  chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "YOURPAGEIDHERE");
  chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v12.0'
  });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Error:
[image]

I already Whitelisted the Domains inside FB Advanced Messaging. I'm not sure if I missed something else on the code.

Comment: What's your referrer policy set to? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin#debug-tips

Comment: Ive got the below info on my pages in inspect network headers. Im checking it if i can fix it via HTML or in another way..any help?
`Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`

Comment: That should still send the origin portion of the referrer, so that's probably fine. (You could check if a referrer is actually send with the iframe request, to make sure.)

Comment: yeah i mean fb customer chat still working even though they have an error like that. Im just wondering how to fix it.:)

Comment: @clarkf yep me too, it's working, but with error log in console, u know why?

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting this error. I found that the `pageId` I was using was wrong. These errors come only when your `pageId` is wrong or the domain is not whitelisted properly (I even tried with a ngrok url and it worked).

So the steps which I followed were:

1. In business.facebook.com go to inbox from sidebar and select chat plugin.
   [image: Facebook Business inbox screenshot]
2. Click on setup to add your domain.
   [image]
3. Pick a setup method(standard for react/nextjs) and setup chat plugin(add language, domain , copy code and paste it)
   [image]
4. You can add multiple domains
   [image]
5. You will get `pageId` already embedded
   [image]

Use this code and paste it in `_document.js` file in `nextjs` and after deploying it will work perfectly.
If there is any confusion, please let me know.

Thanks, Happy Coding

Comment: worked for me with ngrok url. thanks

Comment: facing cors issue with mvc views.

Comment: facebook ui changes so quickly, very annoying. I can't find 'chat plugin' in 'inbox' page

Answer (score 3):

In settings page > advanced messaging > Whitelisted domains.
Add your domain. Verify if your domain is in https or http.

After go to the configuration plugin pannel > configure and add your domain.

Answer (score 1):

One of the [Facebook requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting) is to have an HTTPS domain. HTTP will not be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same error, besides whitelisted domains, I removed age/country restrictions, and it works.

doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin/?locale=en_US

[image: 1]

Comment: Was there any steps took to solve your same error or are they mostly the same steps as the other answer posted?

Comment: @treckstar no other steps, just follow official instruction, and don't restrict Age/Country on Page Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting your domain on facebook should fix this problem.

You can find it on Page Settings > New Pages Experience > Advanced Messaging > Whitelisted Domains

[image: FB admin panel screenshot]

Also if you just type yourdomain.com without 'www', it will still not work, you can bypass this by adding this line of code to your .htaccess file.

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This redirect non-www inputs to www